# Multiple ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, byte[], byte[]> in one single spring microservice

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am developing a microservice where in i am required to query two different microsercvices by using spring kafka ReplyingKafkaTemplate.

when i tried this with one microservice it is working fine by providing a single replying topic as below

```
@Bean
public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, byte[], byte[]> replyKafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, byte[]> pf,
        KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, byte[]> container) {
    return new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, container);

}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, byte[]> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(),
            new ByteArrayDeserializer());
}

@Bean
public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, byte[]> replyContainer(ConsumerFactory<String, byte[]> cf) {
    ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(**queryesultTopic**);
    return new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(cf, containerProperties);
}
```

but now i want two different topics to configure. and wondering how to do this in spring kafka config.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a `ReplyingKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(ProducerRecord<K, V> record)`, you can specify a `KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC` header.

See more info in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.10.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#replying-template):

> See the section called “Forwarding Listener Results using @SendTo” for more information about sending replies; in this case we use the default header `KafKaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC` to indicate which topic the reply goes to.